# GIMP - Change color levels by different amounts from left to right

Tags: gimp

Lets say I have an image in GIMP (one layer) and I want to adjust some aspect of the image, but I want to apply that transformation at different levels to different points on the image. For example, lets say I'd like to increase the yellows on the left side of the image. Is there some way to set up the transformation to apply 100% to the left side, and then smoothly weaken the transformation as you move from left to right (for example) until on the right side of the image, the transformation doesn't get applied at all?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. before applying the effect, just create a selection gradient, where the selection is 100% on the left, and 0% on the right (manually, this is done in "quickmask" mode with the blend tool, with a white-to-black gradient), then apply your effect
2. slightly more complex, but give more control as a manual procedure, and is likely easier to code in a script:

   - duplicate the layer
   - apply the color change in full to the copy (topmost)
   - add a layer mask to that copy
   - fill the layer mask with a white-to-black gradient
   - if needed you can interactively fine tune the gradient using the Curves tool on the layer mask
   - merge down the copy if needed (or get a "frozen" copy with `Layer>New from visible`)